# In omnet++ can handleMessage handle any class other than cMessage?

Tags: omnet++

I want to pass a variable of type MyPacket to handleMessage it gives error.

> ```
> packet MyPacket
> {  string msg;
>  int srcAddress;
>  int destAddress;
> };
> ```

Comment: You really shouldn't call handleMessage() yourself. Just schedule the event, and the simulation kernel will call handleMessage at the time, and in the way it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyPacket` will be converted into a C++ class `MyPacket` which inhertis from `cPacket`. And `cPacket` inherits from `cMessage` so it will be handled by `handleMessage`. However, in `handleMessage` you have to recognize and cast your packet, for example this way:

```
void YourSimpleModule::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   MyPacket * packet = dynamic_cast<MyPacket*> (msg);
   if (packet != nullptr) {
       // it is MyPacket
   } else {
       // other message
   }
```